# How do I load the current items in cart of the anonymous user?

Tags: commerce

I am working on a custom module for our payment system using Drupal 8 and Commerce 2. When a user removes and item for the cart or updates the quantity, I need to sync the two systems (our internal and Drupal commerce's cart). Our site has one store and all products are associated with that store.

I need to be able to load (and loop) over all the items still in the cart after the CartOrderItemRemoveEvent and the CartOrderItemUpdateEvent events. I tried using the following code, but the order is an empty array, despite the cart still having other items in it.

```php
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); //Which is 0 for anonymous
$order = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadByProperties(['uid' => $user->get('uid')->value, 'cart' => '0']);
```

Is there a way to get the anonymous user's cart and a list of items still in that cart?

//updated

```
 public function cartItemRemoved(CartOrderItemRemoveEvent $event) {
      $cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
      $cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
      $order_items = $cart->order_items->referencedEntities();
    \Drupal::logger('current cart items')->info('<pre><code>' . print_r(json_encode($order_items), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get the current anonymous user's cart

```
  $cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
  $cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
```

> Get a list of items still in that user's cart

```
$order_items = $cart->order_items->referencedEntities();
```

---

#### Bonus

```
$cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
```

Update order item

```
$cart_manager->updateOrderItem($cart, $order_item);
```

Remove order item

```
$cart_manager->removeOrderItem($cart, $order_item);
```

Empty cart

```
$cart_manager->emptyCart($cart);
```

Create order item

```
$order_item = $cart_manager->createOrderItem($entity, $quantity);
```

Add order item

```
$cart_manager->addOrderItem($order_item);
```

Comment: When I try to log the value of the $cart or the $order_items, it comes up empty. I updated my post to show the code I am using

Comment: `$cart` is an object, `$order_items` is an array containing `order_item` objects. If you want to inspect these, I suggest you use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s Kint module and do `kint($cart);` for example. You'll need to give anonymous user permission to use Kint

Comment: Although, if your cartItemRemoved is triggered with ajax, you wont see the kint dump. You could tempotsrily move the code inside thst funtion into your theme's preprocess_page function just to see that it's working.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to dump the $order_items also and it came up as an empty array. The remove item is not in ajax. Can you tell me the expected keys for each array order items so I can loop over them and see? I'll add kint also but I am using Drupal's logger and also writing the results to a file.

Comment: I added kint and I am able to see that $order_items has one item in it but I can't seem to dump the value of it.

Comment: Your can access the order_item object protected values like this, for example, if you want the title, loop through the `$order_items` array, `foreach ($order_items as $order_item) { kint($order_item->title->value); }` If you want the quantity use `$order_item->quantity->value`, if you want the unit price use  `$order_item->unit_price->value` etc...

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Actually, one last bother...how do I get to the sku?

Comment: Found it:  $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity(); then $sku = $product_variation->getSku();