# Setting $order_item->setUnitPrice($price, TRUE);) stops cart items being merged, how to prevent this?

Tags: commerce

Drupal Commerce 2, with Drupal 9.

In the CART_ENTITY_ADD event, if i set $order_item->setUnitPrice($price, TRUE); identical items added to the cart get added as new order items, but I want them to be merged.

If I comment out this line in my code the items get merged as expected and their quantity is summed.

How do i set the unit price without the order items being treated as distinct order items?

Relevant code of the CART_ENTITY_ADD event:

```
public function addToCart(CartEntityAddEvent $event) {
    $order_item = $event->getOrderItem();
    // update order item
    $order_item->setUnitPrice($price, TRUE);
    $order_item->save();
}
```

Comment: Let me see the whole picture. Can you post the entire code that gets runned on the `CART_ENTITY_ADD` event?

Comment: Hey @No Sssweat - I've updated my question with the full code. I don't think most of the code is relevant to the issue, as when I remove the $order_item->setUnitPrice($price, TRUE); line it works as expected and the items and quantities are merged. I think the Commerce OrderItemMatcher must not want to merge items when the unit price is set like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmmm rather than `order_item->save();`, try using the cart manager

```
// get the cart
$cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
$cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
// update the cart
$cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
$order_item->setUnitPrice($price, TRUE);
$cart_manager->updateOrderItem($cart, $order_item);
```

<sub>**Bonus:** [Some methods/functions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/295118/27710) you might find useful.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually ended up moving the pricing logic into a price resolver instead. Thats probably where it should belong anyway. Everything works properly when the pricing logic is moved out of the CART_ENTITY_ADD event and into the price resolver.